# Issue with .each() and eval()

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, knockout.js, eval

I'm using Knockout to create an Equation evaluated using data from json object

```
var EqunCreated = ["Salary", "Tax", "Gross_Salary"];

$.each(EqunCreated, function (index, lhs) {
    var Equation = "self." + lhs + "=ko.computed(function(){ return self.Eqn() && eval(self.Eqn()).toFixed(2); })";
    console.log(eval("self." + lhs + "=ko.computed(function(){ return self.Eqn() && eval(self.Eqn()).toFixed(2); })"));
    console.log(lhs);
});
```

I'm having a issue here. Getting error

```
function h(){if(0<arguments.length)return"function"===typeof v?v.apply(d,arguments):j(Error("Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.")),this;n||g();b.r.Wa(h);return l}
```

But if I evaluate `self.Eqn()` I'm getting correct answers.

How to fix this?

Comment: @dreamweiver: it's in the question. please read

Comment: You are not showing an error. You are showing a piece of code.

Comment: function h(){if(0<arguments.length)return"function"===typeof v?v.apply(d,arguments):j(Error("Cannot write a value to a ko.computed unless you specify a 'write' option. If you wish to read the current value, don't pass any parameters.")),this;n||g();b.r.Wa(h);return l}

This is what i get in console

Comment: Yes. This is because you are console logging the function. This is not an error. .computed returns a new function. You are writing it to the console.

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what self is, but I do not think you need to use eval

```
var EqunCreated = ["Salary", "Tax", "Gross_Salary"];

$.each(EqunCreated, function (index, lhs) {
    var Equation = self[lhs] = ko.computed(function(){ return self.Eqn() && parseFloat(self.Eqn()).toFixed(2); });

    console.log(Equation());
});
```

Comment: Self is $this. I have to go through eval cause this string is to bind the ko observables. I have to evaluate that

Comment: But you are only evaluating the assingment of .computed to a property "lhs" on self. You do not need to use eval for that.

Comment: And instead of that second `eval` you likely should use `parseFloat` (or `Math.round` in the first place)